# Wormsinger/Wormfeeder Runes & related Keys - can you have more than one at a time?

Tags: destiny

I've been holding on to a [Key of Yuul](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Key_of_Yuul) for quite a while, mostly because I just have not gotten around to looking up a walk-through to point me in the direction of the chest. Meanwhile, I've noticed it seems that no Wormsinger/Wormfeeder Runes are spawning for me.

Are these Runes just extremely rare, or do I have to use the Key before a new Rune will drop?

Comment: what are you doing to spawn more wormfeeder runes?

Comment: @Timelord64 I don't even recall exactly how my first one dropped. But I've been participating in quite a wide range of Dreadnaught-based activities since I first got the Key of Yuul. So, it's probably safe to assume I've been through pretty much everything. Or, I'm at least confident that I've done enough to have repeated whatever activity spawned that first rune. Several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wormfeeder Runes only drop from the ultra Ogre that spawns after someone has used a Wormsinger rune. You can only have one of these at a time.

Based on personal experience, the named keys also prevent holding another of these runes at the same time. I had one of the named keys in my inventory, and another player used a Wormsinger rune. When we killed the Ogre, a Wormfeeder rune didn't drop for me.

So use those named keys as soon as you get them in order to prevent you from missing the opportunity of getting additional runes and keys.

Comment: I'm not so sure the Ogre is the only thing that drops the Runes. I think it's a random from any Hive Major/Ultra on the Dreadnaught. (And I'm pretty sure I've gotten it from others.) Otherwise, where'd the *first* Wormfeeder Rune come from? The rest seems pretty solid - I spent the key I had and very quickly got another Rune drop. Didn't see another one until after I'd gone through the whole process again, etc.

Comment: @Iszi There are two runes: Wormsinger and Wormfeeder. Wormsinger runes can drop from any Hive enemy you kill on the Dreadnaught. When you use this so spawn the Hive hunting party, killing the Ultra Ogre will drop a Wormfeeder rune. Both runes have the same (or nearly the same) icon, so it is very easy to confuse them.

Comment: Ah, yeah. We were talking about two slightly different things. So, it's (relatively) easy to get the Rune that starts the whole process (Wormsinger), but the second-step Rune (Wormfeeder) only comes from the Ogre. And once you get one of the "Worm*" Runes, you can't get another until you follow the process all the way through and use the resulting Key.

Comment: @Iszi I'd say the Wormsinger rune is harder to get, since it is a random drop. Once you have that, it's only a matter of using that rune at one of the podiums around the hull breach to trigger the scouting party and kill the Ogre.

Comment: Once you have a Wormsinger, the Wormfeeder is certainly easier to get, as it's practically guaranteed. And you also have a chance of getting a Wormfeeder without even having a Wormsinger, if you run into an Ogre that's been summoned by someone else. But the first method requires you already having a Wormfeeder rune to begin with, and the second relies on pure coincidence - even less predictable (and, probably for most, less frequent) than the random chance associated with the Wormsinger drop.